Angular Spreadsheet ExportData from the grille to Excel FIle
I'm working with x-data-spreadsheet and I want to export all my data in the grille into a file excel.
I used this.spreadsheet.getData() to get all the data than try to export it but nothing. output are array of objects.
exportDataToExcel(): void {

    const data = this.spreadsheet.getData(); 
    console.log("Data : ",data);
    console.log("TYPE : ",typeof data);
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(data)
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1'); 
    const fileName = 'spreadsheet_data.xlsx';
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, fileName); 

I am expecting to export all my data in the grille to a excel file

I use this code in order to generate XL files. Note how the method support 2 ways of generating Excel files : either through native HTML table, either through JSON.
Though, your Json should be a "flat" type with 1 level of key <=> value where value is juste a simple String or number, not a complex object
exportToExcel(elemRef: ElementRef, tabName: string, fileName: string, json = null) {
  const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = json ? XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json) : 
  XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(elemRef.nativeElement);
  const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, tabName);

  /* save to file */
  XLSX.writeFile(wb, fileName);
}

